# Server Rendering with React issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I want my server code to be written in ES-5 itself.In my `server.js` file i have imported the client.js file.
inside `client.js`

```
 // i am only pasting the necessary codes i have written. 
 export default render = (req, res) => {
    const componentHTML = ReactDOM.renderToString(
        <Provider store={store}>
          <RouterContext {...props} />
        </Provider>); 
res.status(200).send(`<html>
                      <head><title>Test</title></head>
                      <body><div id="app">${componentHTML}</div>
                      <script type="text/javascript" src="./app.js"></script>
                      </body></html>`);

 }
```

Whereas my server.js file is

```
import App from './client.js';
const express = require('express');
app.use(express.static(publicPath));
app.get('*', App);
```

When i bundle my server.js file, client.js file and run then it **works perfectly**.
but i want to import my bundled client file in my server.js file so that i can run simply `node ./server.js`.
So i tried changing server.js file which looks like

```
const App = require('./dist/client.bundle.js');
console.log(App) // output is {} why ??;
const express = require('express');
app.use(express.static(publicPath));
app.get('*', App); // i also tried App.default both didn't work
```

after running this i got this error.

> /home/Work/test/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:196
>           throw new Error(msg);
>           ^ Error: Route.get() requires callback functions but got a [object Object]

Why am i getting this error if i import the bundled file in my server code ?

Thanks

Comment: What are you using as a server? It seems to be Express, right? If you are using Express, I think you have to generate build through `npm run build', and then just return the index.html generated by build comand.

Comment: The bundle file should be loaded as **<script src="./dist/client.bundle.js">**. Now what you are showing is that you have **two** servers. The code you showed in client.js should be part of your server.js. **client.js** is supposed to have only client code.

Comment: Please go through this boilerplate code https://github.com/reactGo/reactGo/blob/master/server/index.js , i am following this architecture